# Comment appelle-t-on le fait d'utiliser les codes d'un autre genre ?

Tags: terminologie, demande-de-mot, figure-de-style, littérature

En littérature, existe-t-il un mot qualifiant le fait d'utiliser les codes d'un certain genre littéraire pour écrire sur un tout autre sujet ?

Exemples :

- une recette de cuisine épistolaire
- un huis-clos homérique
- une saga "noire"

Comment: Si tu cherches un néologisme (imprononçable et pédant ?), je propose *transtropisme*.

Comment: J'aime beaucoup ce néologisme !

Comment: Merci. Pour préciser, je pensais notamment à cette ["référence"](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_Tropes) pour la racine *trope*, plutôt qu'à [celle-ci](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trope_%28rh%C3%A9torique%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trois termes peuvent s'appliquer.

> **Pastiche**

s’applique si on parle de la création d'une œuvre nouvelle, seul le style est copié.

["Le pastiche peut être défini comme l’imitation, parodique ou **non**, du style d’un auteur ou **d’un courant littéraire**."](http://contextes.revues.org/59)

> **Parodie**

S'il y a une intention de moquerie. Toutes les parodies sont des pastiches, tous les pastiches ne sont pas parodiques.

> [**Transposition**](http://www.assistancescolaire.com/eleve/1ES/francais/reviser-le-cours/les-differents-procedes-de-reecriture-1_f301)

Si on parle plutôt d'une réécriture d'une œuvre existante, mais en changeant son style.  Le terme englobe plus que la littérature, on  parle de [transposition](http://www.cndp.fr/presence-litterature/index.php?id=95) aussi quand on passe d'un art à un autre (Musique-->littérature-->cinéma).

Voir sur le lien de transposition les nuances entre ces trois termes.

Comment: Je suis à peu près sûr que tout le monde pense qu'un pastiche est forcément parodique (la plupart des dictionnaires mentionnent "parodie" comme un synonyme) mais a priori c'est bien ce mot.

Answer (score 4):

Sur la [page de Wikipédia en Français concernant le terme équivalent en musique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_%28musique%29), on propose ***chiasmatypie***, terme lui-même empruntée à la biologie ("Théorie selon laquelle les chiasmas observables cytologiquement en fin de prophase I [de la division cellulaire] sont la conséquence d'interchanges qui ont eu lieu antérieurement entre les chromosomes homologues."), ou de construction accidentellement identique, je n'en sais rien. Pour faire dans le simple, on pourrait parler d'**hybridation**.

Généralement, on emploie plutôt ce genre de terme dans le sens plus général d'un mélange des conventions des deux genres, mais cette forme spécifique dont tu parles peut parfaitement être conçue comme une simple application du même concept.